# What does norm='l2' in sklearn.preprocessing.normalize do for matrix normalization?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn

I normalized `scipy.sparse` matrix `sA` here by using `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`. I read the document but not understand about `norm='l...'` well, so I tested it.

`norm='l1'` went ok and I got the sum result as expected as 1 in all row.

```
A = np.array([[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[1,0,4]])
sA = sp.csr_matrix(A)   
normsA = normalize(sA, norm='l1', axis=0)
print normsA
print "---"
print sum(normsA)

>>(0, 0)    0.5
  (2, 0)    0.5
  (0, 1)    1.0
  (1, 2)    0.428571428571
  (2, 2)    0.571428571429
  ---
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 1)    1.0
  (0, 2)    1.0
```

However, when I tried `l2`, I can't find how it is normalizing the matrix. Sum of the matrix or the transposed matrix is not equal to one. What `l2` does for normalizing here?

```
normsA2 = normalize(sA, norm='l2', axis=0)
print sum(normsA2)
print sum(normsA2.T)

>>(0, 0)    1.41421356237
  (0, 1)    1.0
  (0, 2)    1.4
  (0, 0)    1.70710678119
  (0, 1)    0.6
  (0, 2)    1.50710678119
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is using the [l2 norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) (or euclidean norm/distance), in other words the sum of the squares of the elements gives one.

The following outputs the expected vector of ones:

```
sum(normsA2 ** 2, axis=0)
```